# Alexa skill response pagination

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In one intent of my skill have lot of records to display or read for user; i want to paginate response of that intent

Example:

**User:** how many announcements are in the system

**Alexa:** there are 6. first 4 are (announcement 1, announcement 2, announcement 3, announcement 4)

Do you want to hear more?

**User:** Yes

**Alexa:** Next 2 announcements are (announcement 5, announcement 6)

Answer (score 0):

Use `AMAZON.YesIntent` intent to capture **"Yes"** inputs from the user.

When the user asks for announcements use `sessionAttributes` along with your response to keep track of the read announcement indexes. So that when the user says **"Yes"**, you can use this session attribute to read the next set of announcements. You can also set a `STATE` attribute too, so that you can validate the state in `AMAZON.YesIntent` handler before you give the next set of announcements.

Ex:

```
...
"sessionAttributes": {
    "announcements_index": [0,1,2,3],
    "STATE": "READ_ANNOUNCEMENTS"
  }
...
```

When the user say **"Yes"**, in your `AMAZON.YesIntent` handler check whether the state is `READ_ANNOUNCEMENTS` and based on the `announcements_index` give the next set of announcements from your announcements list. And in `sessionAttributes` update  the `announcements_index`.

There is chance that user might say **"No"**, for **"Do you want to hear more?"**.  So add a `AMAZON.NoIntent` too and handle it accordingly.

Do not forget to clear `announcements_index` and `STATE` when use case is done.

More on `sessionAttributes` and Response Parameters [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-parameters)